# Show that a function is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ f $ be a bounded continuous function on $ \mathbb R^3$ that supported on the unit ball $ B(0,1)$ and satisfies the condition $ \sup_{ x, y \in \mathbb R^3, x \neq y } \frac{ |f(x) - f(y) | }{ |x - y |^\alpha } < \infty$ for some $ 0 < \alpha < 1$. How do I show that $ u (x) : = \int_{ \mathbb R^3 } \frac{ f(y) }{ | x -y |} dy $ is bounded?

---

I tried like writing $u(x) : = \int_{ \mathbb R ^3} \frac{ f(y) - f(x) + f(x) }{ |x -y | } dy $, but this does not help. And I know $u(x)$ is continuous but the support is $ \mathbb R^3$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that if $|x|\to\infty$, then your function $u(x)$ goes to zero. So, you can split $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a big compact ball where it has a maximum, and the rest where it is small. (More work is required to show that $u(x)$ is continuous and everywhere defined)

Comment: @PeterFranek You are absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterFranek: Isn't u(x) continuous for all $x\neq y$, by the FTC? I mean u(x) is differentiable wherever the integrand is continuous; f(x) is assumed continuous, so we only need $x \neq y$.

Comment: @user112564: Maybe we can use some sort of Real-analysis version of the Riemann Removable singularities theorem, since u(x) is continuous for $x\neq y$  , by the FTCalculus  as a ratio of continuous functions, and $u(x)$ is supported in $B(0,1)$ (since f(x) is supported there )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that since $f$ is supported in $B=B_0(1)$, it is bounded by some constant $|f|\le M$:
$$u(x)=\int_B\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|}dy$$
Thus if $x\notin B$ we have:
$$|u(x)|\le\int_B\frac{|f(y)|}{|x-y|}\le vol(B)M\frac{1}{d(x,B)}$$
If, as you said, you proved that $u$ is continuous, then we are done, since $u$ is certainly bounded on $B$ (which is compact) and we have just showed that it is bounded outside.